# 4g vs 5g ping in india

Tags: ping, isp

I am playing an online game and get ping as follows -

1. With 4g - 150ms
2. With 5g - almost 145ms

These are my two questions I didn't found on Google or chatgpt.

1. Why does it has almost the same ping when I am using the upgraded version of 4g (5g) as well.

I know that the distance between the device and server cannot be changed, but as its 5g it must travel that distance faster. Right?

I use airtel 5g and 4g at full network strength.

2. I also heard that both airtel and Jio operates with the Non-standard (NSA) infra instead of SA which could improve the speed but can it improve the ping as well?

Comment: There isn't necessarily a connection between the bandwidth of a network and the latency to a server.  You can have high bandwidth and high latency to a server.  So you have similar latency to a connection isn't entirely unexpected.

Answer (score 2):

> Why does it has almost the same ping when I am using the upgraded version of 4g (5g) as well.
>
> I know that the distance between the device and server cannot be changed, but as its 5g it must travel that distance faster. Right?

Because the "4G/5G" that you're using is *only* the radio link from your device to the nearest cell tower. (And maybe from the cell tower into the operator's core network.)

The rest of the path, from your operator to the server, is neither "4G" nor "5G" at all – it's Ethernet over fiber optic cables.

If I had to guess, your 4G/5G connection is responsible for maybe 10-20ms, while the remaining 130ms or so is the long-distance fiber links from the operator to the server, the same path either way.

(You can find out more accurate numbers by pinging a server at your own ISP, e.g. the operator's local DNS server – this will tell you *mostly* the 4G/5G latency.

The small ping packets probably still take roughly the same time travelling across the air either way – from what I know, the difference in latency is more due to 5G being better at dividing "air time" between all clients connected to the same cell tower, and/or maybe due to it having fewer 5G users than 4G users at this time, so that your device basically gets more chances to actually send the packets out.)